# Filter by multiple values (Angular 2/7, TypeScript)

Tags: angular, typescript, filter

I can't filtered "listProduct" by multiple values. How do filter by multiple values?

I have tried write after through comma but not working. I not found solution in "google".

```js
searchFilter = () => {
    this.listProducts = this.listProductsOrigin.filter(e =>
      e.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.searchValue.toLocaleLowerCase())
    );

    this.loading = false;
    // tslint:disable-next-line: semicolon
  };
```

I have tried do it:

```js
searchFilter = () => {
    this.listProducts = this.listProductsOrigin.filter(e =>
      e.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.searchValue.toLocaleLowerCase()),
e.description.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.searchValueDesc.toLocaleLowerCase())
    );

    this.loading = false;
    // tslint:disable-next-line: semicolon
  };
```

but not working.

Comment: You need `||` between two condition

Comment: Like this:  `searchFilter = () => {
    this.listProducts = this.listProductsOrigin.filter(e =>
      e.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.searchValue.toLocaleLowerCase()) 
      ||
      e.description.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.searchValueDesc.toLocaleLowerCase())

    );
    this.loading = false;
    // tslint:disable-next-line: semicolon
  };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typescript compiler should be warning you about your attempted solution. The `filter()` method takes a function that returns a bool value so you probably want something like this:

```
this.listProducts = this.listProductsOrigin.filter(e =>
      e.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.searchValue.toLocaleLowerCase()) || e.description.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.searchValueDesc.toLocaleLowerCase())
    );
```

or maybe:

```
this.listProducts = this.listProductsOrigin.filter(e =>
      e.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.searchValue.toLocaleLowerCase()) && e.description.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.searchValueDesc.toLocaleLowerCase())
    );
```

depending on whether you want to combine the filter clauses with an AND or an OR operation

Comment: In second variant find is correct but with empty value is not working

Comment: not 100% sure I am following you but of course if you try to call `toLocaleLowerCase()` on something that is null or undefined then you will hit an error. It would be difficult to debug without more information. You could, for example, filter out all the blanks before hand (assuming they are to be excluded rather than included) but that's a different question really...

Comment: if values is empty that output all result

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
searchFilter = () => {
    this.listProducts = this.listProductsOrigin.filter(e =>
      e.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.searchValue.toLocaleLowerCase()) 
      || e.description.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.searchValueDesc.toLocaleLowerCase())
    );
    this.loading = false;
    // tslint:disable-next-line: semicolon
};
```

Comment: Good search only by first criteria